# Error when sync with Git from eclipse on mac osx

Tags: java, eclipse, git, macos

I have Git repository, and I have two PC (Mac and Windows) with Eclipse Mars. I have add plugin Git. So if I change the project from Eclipse in Windows, and I try to commit the modifier, works, but if I try to open Eclipse from my Mac then open view Git, right click on Remote Tracking then click on "Synchronize with Workspace

[image]

My eclipse locks, on the right view I can see the scroller every time at 0%. 
The error is like this:

> Internal error memory limit exceeded

How can I fixed it?

Comment: Have you tried using the git command line instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your eclipse is running low on memory.

You need to increase the memory allocation for eclipse.
Please check the link here to find it http://crunchify.com/increase-eclipse-memory-size-to-avoid-oom-on-startup/

cheers,

Saurav